# Jenkins: build one job after another with some delay

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 jobs in Jenkins: QA and Dev.
In Dev job I checked "Build after other projects are built" option and set project name =  QA so that QA job will be built after Dev job is built.
But in my particular situation  I need that QA job started building in 5 mins after Dev job is built. How can I do it? maybe I can add some build step with some data to add this delay ?

TIA,
Anna

Comment: Why wait 5 minutes?  Is it possible to  directly check to see if whatever you're waiting for has happened/completed?

Comment: Because your job, if dependent upon multiple upstream triggers, could end up kicking off multiple jobs vs. just one.

If EITHER trigger happens, wait xx minutes THEN run the job.

This appears to be exactly what we are needing right now.

A) Upstream project rolls out change.
B) 10 downstream modules are triggered to ensure nothing breaks.
C) Bottom job, connected to them all, also needs to run, but only once.

Quiet time of, say, 10 minutes, appears to be what's needed.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is a ["Quiet Period"](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/quiet-period-feature) option in the Advanced Project Options available. You can enter a value of 300 (its in seconds) to delay the start of the job by 5 mins.

Comment: Update: now this `Quiet Period` option is a check box in Build Triggers option.

Comment: It can also be set in the Jenkinsfile: options { quietPeriod(30) }
See Options Section in https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

Comment: This looks like exactly what we need for our project! An impacting change can come from a dozen parent jobs OR a grandparent job, currently causing a huge cascde.

Adjust quietPeriod to something like 30 minutes may be what we need to cut things down to a single build instead of 15.

Comment: Fisher Coder: Update: Quiet Period option isn't anymore in Build Triggers option.

Comment: Note:  "Quiet Period" option in the Advanced Project Options will be default system-wide value and useful for SCM tools like CVS that commit file changes one by one, rather than grouped together,not for Subversion, Git or Mercurial, commits are atomic.

Comment: Note that the semantics of quiet period are not really that of a delay. If a job has been in the queue for a long time, it will STILL WAIT ANOTHER 5 seconds to start. In the OP's example, if the DEV job and QA job take 1 second to execute, 100 DEV jobs will complete in 100 seconds, but the dependant 100 QA jobs will take 500 seconds. 
If anyone has found a way to implement actual delay... not a quiet period, then I would really like to know.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the REST api, you can add a url get value like this:

`http://jenkins/job/jobname/build?delay=4`

That will delay 4 seconds and start the job.

Comment: Is there a way to pass this delay if you are not using the REST api? ie. if you are using the Parameterized Build Plugin? I tried adding "delay" as an additional parameter, and it had no effect

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can add that to the URL of the job and run it as usual.

https://your-jenkins.url/jobs/name-of-job/build?delay=5

Give it a whirl. I don't have my vpn connections right now to test it myself.

Comment: But I'm not running the job via URL, I'm triggering it from another job, using the Jenkins UI (the Parameterized Build Plugin). There doesn't seem to be a place to add a delay there?

Comment: Note that `delay` behaves the same as Quiet Period. It does not delay the addition to the queue, it delays the start of the job after the previous job.

Answer (score 2):

I know the topic is quite old but in case sameone else is looking for an answer here it is. 
When using parametrized build remember to escape "&". You can replace it with: "%26" or put the whole URL in quotes. It will work. Please also remember to use delay as first parameter.

Comment: This looks like exactly the answer I need, but unfortunately you didn't include enough detail for me to figure it out. I may get it with trial and error, but if you could clarify this answer I would upvote it.

Comment: Karol Majewski: Can you explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

To make it simpler with out worrying about trigger from URL using delay, there is a Jenkins plugin which helps to schedule the job on the fly with as much as delay you need (configurable when ever you are running build and supports parameterized builds as well). For more details please check [Plugin Pags](https://plugins.jenkins.io/schedule-build), [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/schedule-build-plugin)