# Trigger Jenkins Job after Artifactory Upload

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I have two Jenkins jobs.

Job 1: Uploads build to artifactory

Job 2: Downloads build from artifactory and does some stuff with it

Right now, Job 1 triggers Job 2 using the Parameterized Build Plugin (Job 2 is shared amongst many teams at my company, so I don't want to change it too much - it's a parameterized job that takes an artifactory URL)

The problem is, it seems like the artifact doesn't always finish uploading to artifactory before Job 2 is triggered. Sometimes Job 2 gets a 404 when it tries to download the artifact. Is there some way to 1) prevent triggering Job 2 until the artifact has uploaded? or 2) pass the artifact directly from Job 1 to Job 2 w/out needing to do an upload and a download? (the former would be preferable, since option 2 would require changing Job 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your option 1, you can use the [Naginator](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin) plugin to reschedule a job 2 if it fails.

Regarding the option 2, you can use the [Copy Artifact](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) plugin. It will allow the job 2 to copy the artifacts from the job 1.

Personally, I prefer the option 1. Artifactory is the right place to store binaries :)

There is a 3rd solution by using the quiet period setting on the job 2 to delay the start ([Jenkins: build one job after another with some delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748993/jenkins-build-one-job-after-another-with-some-delay)).

Comment: Thanks - is there any way to just delay the run of job 2 to begin with? Seems silly to kick it off knowing it's going to fail.

Comment: Yep, there is a quiet period setting you can use on the job 2, please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748993/jenkins-build-one-job-after-another-with-some-delay. I've added this solution in my answer. Please vote if it solved your issue :)

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem, since job 2 is used by a lot of people - I don't want them all to have a delay - I only want the delay when job 2 is triggered by job 1. Is there some way to add the delay to the trigger?

Comment: One dirty solution is to add a shell/batch post-build step on the job 1, and add a sort of wait (sleep N secondes for example).