# Jenkins: Trigger build with some delay

Tags: jenkins, build, delay

Is there any way to trigger one build after another but with some delay.
I tried this solution with Quiet Period from here -> [Jenkins: build one job after another with some delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748993/jenkins-build-one-job-after-another-with-some-delay)
but seems to not working - second job was started instantly.
Is there any way to pass delay to downstream as trigger parameter becasue the answers are not clear.

Comment: you can add a post unix command to sleep for 30 seconds after each of your jobs. Its just a workaround

Answer (score 0):

you can add the delay=123456sec parameter when triggering a build by URL. I'm sure it's available in other methods of triggering a build